# Android sqlite id missing after update

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-syncadapter

after I update an object in my syncAdapter I can't get it back by id again. It seems that the id get lost after the update. What leaves behind is a null object.
Here's my source code how I update the object:

```
@Override
public void updateUserThread(Context ctxt, UserThread userThread, boolean notified)
{
    try
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHandler.TOPIC, userThread.getTopic());
        if(userThread.getCreationDate() != null)
            values.put(DBHandler.USER_THREAD_CREATION_DATE, userThread.getCreationDate().getTime());

        values.put(DBHandler.THREAD_TYPE, Helper.threadTypeToString(userThread.getThreadType()));
        values.put(DBHandler.MEETING_PLACE, userThread.getMeetingPlace());
        values.put(DBHandler.SUBJECT, userThread.getSubject());
        values.put(DBHandler.SENT, Helper.convertBooleanToInt(userThread.isSent()));

        if(userThread.getStartDate() != null)
            values.put(DBHandler.START_DATE, userThread.getStartDate().getTime()); //Helper.getDateTime(

        values.put(DBHandler.FOR_ALL, userThread.isForAll());
        values.put(DBHandler.ID_SERVER, userThread.getIdServer());

        if(userThread.getAuthor() != null)
            values.put(DBHandler.ID_USER_FK, userThread.getAuthor().getIdUser());

        if(notified)
        {
            ctxt.getContentResolver().update(TeamChannelProvider.USER_THREAD_URI, values, DBHandler.ID_USER_THREAD + "=" + "?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userThread.getIdUserThread())});
        }
        else
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            long status = db.update(TABLE_USER_THREAD, values, DBHandler.ID_USER_THREAD + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userThread.getIdUserThread())});
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Status: " + status);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "ERROR - DBHandlerTeamChannel -> updateUserThread", exc);
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "UserThread updated with ID " + (notified ? "(notified) " : "not notified ") + userThread.getIdUserThread() + ", Server-ID: " + userThread.getIdServer());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of DBHandler.ID_USER_THREAD? Have you checked the value of userThread.getIdUserThread()? Maybe your DBHandler.ID_USER_THREAD value matches some other DBHandler.XXXX value and you are overriding the ID.

Comment: The constant indeed matches the name of the db field "idUserThread". Could it be possible updating the object within a syncAdapter (other process) can lead to this behavior?